# jQuery new line \n

Tags: javascript, jquery, newline, line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the cleanest way to write a multiline string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589234/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-write-a-multiline-string-in-javascript)

How does one go onto a new line in writing jQuery code not the actual output of the code, for example:

```
$('#foo').append('<div id="bla"> '+\n+'
                  </div>');
```

Something like that.

Comment: @Felix - Great? It didn't show in the any recommendations.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate per se, this asks about the output including the newline character specifically whereas the proposed duplicate asks about multiline strings.  Two different questions with the same answer is all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$('#foo').append('<div id="bla"> \
                 </div>');
```

The slash (\) escapes the newline, allowing the string to span multiple lines

Comment: I think it's a good idea to use `+`.